# `createSQLException` when trying to get all rows in MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a simple table consisting of 4 strings and 2 integers (of which one is an ID).

[image]

I use a special function to get all rows inside that table:

```
public Booking[] displayAllBookings() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Connection con = connect.getConnection();

    PreparedStatement counter = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from bookings");
    ResultSet count = counter.executeQuery();

    Booking[] array = new Booking[count.getInt(1)]; 

    String name = null,surname = null,begindate = null,enddate = null;
    int persons = 0,i=0;

    PreparedStatement posted = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bookings");
    result = posted.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()){
        begindate = result.getString("begindate");
        enddate = result.getString("enddate");
        name = result.getString("Name");
        surname = result.getString("Surname");
        persons = result.getInt("persons");
        Booking temp =  new Booking(begindate,enddate,name,surname,persons);
        array[i++]=temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

But when I execute it I get this exception:

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2472)
at DataBase.DataCommunicatorBooking.displayAllBookings(DataCommunicatorBooking.java:59)
at DataBase.main.displayAll(main.java:125)
at DataBase.main.main(main.java:71)
```

I've tried looking up this exception but I can't find anything that corresponds to my problem.

Comment: print all your error please

Comment: is `maxPersons` exist in your table i can't see it?

Comment: sorry guys i had copied the wrong function! the function that's giving me trouble is there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the

```
PreparedStatement counter = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from bookings");
ResultSet count = counter.executeQuery();
```

so I used an `ArrayList` like so:

```
public Booking[] displayAllBookings() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Connection con = connect.getConnection();

        ArrayList<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>(); 

        String name = null,surname = null,begindate = null,enddate = null;
        int persons = 0,i=0;

        PreparedStatement posted = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bookings");
        result = posted.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()){
            begindate = result.getString("begindate");
            enddate = result.getString("enddate");
            name = result.getString("Name");
            surname = result.getString("Surname");
            persons = result.getInt("persons");
            Booking temp =  new Booking(begindate,enddate,name,surname,persons);
            bookings.add(temp);
        }
        return bookings.toArray(new Booking[bookings.size()]);
    }
```

and that solved the problem;

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value of the column ***maxPersons*** which is not even defined in the table... you meant for sure ***persons***

```
 name = result.getString("Name");
 maxPersons = result.getInt("persons");
 Room temp =  new Room(name,maxPersons);
```

Comment: Ok I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

This is because the column "maxPersons" does not exist, you probably ment "persons"

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake... i posted the wrong function